# Three.js Meshline not appearing in 2nd camera

Tags: three.js, mesh

I am using the Meshline library seen here: https://github.com/spite/THREE.MeshLine
to add a thick x,y,z axis to my Three.js scene as can be seen in the picture below.

[image]

In my three.js script I have 2 cameras and one scene. The problem is that the MeshLine appears in the first camera but not the second even though there is one scene.

I am really quite perplexed as to why this is case and I cannot understand why this is happening as all other objects added to the scene appear in BOTH cameras.

Could someone please give me some pointers as to what is going wrong?

I am using the following code to create the thick axis

```
function addHelpers( size = 200 ) {
        scene.remove( gridHelper, axesHelper );
        gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper( size, size / 10 );
        gridHelper.rotation.x = 0.5 * Math.PI;
        function makeAxes(){
            // This function makes a thick axis - as Ben requested
            var graph = new THREE.Object3D();
            //var resolution = new THREE.Vector2( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            var resolution = new THREE.Vector2( 100, 50 );
            function makeLine( geo,color) {
                var g = new MeshLine();
                g.setGeometry( geo );
                var material = new MeshLineMaterial( {
                    useMap: false,
                    color: new THREE.Color(color),
                    opacity: 1,
                    resolution: resolution,
                    sizeAttenuation: !false,
                    lineWidth: 0.025
                });
                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( g.geometry, material );
                mesh.position.set( 0,0,0);
                graph.add( mesh );
            }
            // X axis
            var line = new THREE.Geometry();
            line.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( -30, -30, -30 ) );
            line.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( 30, -30, -30 ) );
            makeLine( line, 0x009500 );
            // Y axis
            var line = new THREE.Geometry();
            line.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(  -30, -30, -30 ) );
            line.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( -30, 30, -30 ) );
            makeLine( line, 0x0000ff );
            // Z axis
            var line = new THREE.Geometry();
            line.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( -30, -30, -30 ) );
            line.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( -30, -30, 30 ) );
            makeLine( line, 0xff0000 );
            return graph
        }
        // Thick axis helper
        axesHelper = makeAxes()
        scene.add(axesHelper)
        scene.add(gridHelper);
    }
```

While I am starting the whole scene with the code and the function above is called in the code below.

```
function initThreejs() {
    width = 300;
    height = 300;
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: 1, antialias: true }  );
    renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff, 1 );
    renderer.setSize( width, height );
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    context1 = canvasPerspective.getContext( '2d' );
    context2 = canvasOrtho.getContext( '2d' );
    camera1 = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40, width / height, 1, 1000 );
    camera1.position.set( -100, -250, 200 );
    camera1.up.set( 0, 0, 1 );
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera1, canvasPerspective );
    controls.maxDistance = 600;
    camera2 = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( width / -3, width / 3, height / 3, 
    height / - 3, 1, 1000 );
    camera2.position.set( 0, 0, 200 );
    camera2.up.set( 0, 0, 1 );
    controls2 = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera2, canvasOrtho );
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    lightAmbient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x444444 );
    scene.add( lightAmbient );
    const size = 100
    lightDirectional = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffeedd );
    lightDirectional.position.set( -size, size, size );
    lightDirectional.shadow.camera.scale.set( 13, 15, 0.5 );
    lightDirectional.castShadow = true;
    scene.add( lightDirectional );
    addHelpers();
    addAssets();
}
```

If helpful the entire code can be seen [here](https://github.com/antonszilasi/spiderAnton/blob/master/sandbox/speed-specification/envelope.html)

Comment: You should provide information about how you instantiate and set the cameras, what their positions, location of the helper relatively to them and so on. Maybe jsfiddle or a code snippet.

Comment: @prisoner849 thank you for your suggestion I have updated my question to be more thorough

Comment: late reply, I have made my own thick (potentially) curved lines; it's easy with circular arcs and straight lines. IE, just use cylinders as your axes. See this jsfiddle for ref: https://jsfiddle.net/u98wssL2/